# Android SQLite custom query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database with 5 columns named col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5
All these columns are type TEXT.
Say, the table's name is my_table and I have 10 entries in the table of database

```
col_1  col_2    col_3   col_4     col_5

001     01       001    John1   Wright1
002     02       002    John2   Wright2
001     02       003    John3   Wright3
003     01       004    John4   Wright4
001     01       005    John5   Wright5
004     01       006    John6   Wright6
001     03       007    John7   Wright7
002     01       008    John8   Wright8
002     02       009    John9   Wright9
005     01       010    John0   Wright0
```

I want to write a function to query to this data base depending on values of col_1 and col_2 and get all possible values of col_4 (array of values) into a list.

Say, I want to query with col_1="001" AND col_2="01", I expect result to be an array of string containing {John1, John5}

```
String [] tableColumns = new String[1];
tableColumns = "col_4";
String whereClause = "col_1=? AND col_2=?";
String [] whereArgs = {col_1_val, col2_val}; //where col_1_val = "001" and col_2_val = "01"

Cursor c = qb.query(db, tableColumns, whereClause , whereArgs , null, null, null, null);
```

Is this correct? If so how to access each element of result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is almost correct.

Using documentation for [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29), you should use:

```
String [] tableColumns = {"col_4"};
String whereClause = "col_1=? AND col_2=?";
String [] whereArgs = {col_1_val, col2_val}; //where col_1_val = "001" and col_2_val = "01"

Cursor c = query(
    true,        //boolean distinct
    "my_table",   //String table
    tableColumns,//String[] columns
    whereClause, //String selection
    whereArgs,   //String[] selectionArgs
    null,        //String groupBy
    null,        //String having
    null,        //String orderBy
    null,        //String limit
    null         //CancellationSignal cancellationSignal
);
```

I, myself, prefer using [`rawQuery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT DISTINCT col_4 FROM my_table WHERE col_1=? AND col_2=?",
    new String[] {col_1_val, col2_val}
);
```

For fecthing results, check [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) methods. Following is a possible method:

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); c.isAfterLast() == false; c.moveToNext()) {
    some_variable=c.getString(0))
}
```

Comment: Thank you LS_dev. It worked like charm! I was using wrong tableColumns data type. You are right, using rawQuery is more readable and simple.